# Strange behavior using loadBytes in P5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I'm trying to load a binary file into an array to operate with it later using loadBytes.

Using the following snippet :

```
function preload()
{
  binFile = loadBytes("file.bin");
}

function setup()
{
    console.log(binFile.bytes.length);
}
```

returns 53864, but the file is just 32767 (32k), plus iterating through the array... it shows just "garbage", nothing compared to the original file.

Any clues?

Comment: Got a [mcve]? Preferably with a much smaller .bin file of course =)

Comment: Also, a sample of the 'garbage' versus whatever you were expecting would be helpful.